# IndexedDB vs Storage

Tags: google-chrome-extension, indexeddb, firefox-addon-webextensions

IndexedDB is often recommended for storing large amount of data in WebExtensions (or Chrome Extension). `"unlimitedStorage"` seems to apply to both IDB and Storage.

In case of non-tabular text data where the indexed searches are not needed, what is the benefit of using IndexedDB over Storage?

They both use object based architecture and there is a great performance overhead in case of IDB.

I tested parsing and saving 4mb data to storage which took less than 1 second while in case of IDB it hung the browser for minutes and I had to forcefully shut it down.

Reference: [Chrome extension store large amounts of data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34060487/chrome-extension-store-large-amounts-of-data)

> Only WebSQL, IndexedDB, chrome.storage.local and HTML5 File System
>   (sandboxed file system) can grow past 5MB limit via "unlimitedStorage"
>   permission.
>
> manifest.json: "permissions": ["unlimitedStorage"]
>
> Provides an unlimited quota for storing HTML5 client-side data, such as databases and local storage files. Without this permission, the extension or app is limited to 5 MB of local storage.

Comment: You can store blobs in IDB

Comment: The `unlimitedStorage` permission applies only to Web SQL Database and application cache. Refer to [crbug 58985](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=58985)

Comment: @Deliaz Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34060487/chrome-extension-store-large-amounts-of-data

Comment: "it hung the browser for minutes and I had to forcefully shut it down" sounds like you're doing it wrong, to be honest. Care to show sample code?

Comment: @xan Well that was not the question but try to parse and write a 4mb CSV file with 275+k records each with multiple properties to indexedDB and see.