# Saving data from chrome app apart from local Storage

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

**How can i save data to database from  chrome app**. I have tried with Local Storage which is inbuilt API of chrome app  but it wont work for me as I have to  manage a large data with chrome App. Basically i need to  store data for my offline chrome app .

I have tried for local storage  and tried to create logs in directory but it wont work for me

```js
chrome.storage.local.set({dataList: dataList}, function () {
 // you can use strings instead of objects
 // if you don't  want to define default values
 chrome.storage.local.get('dataList',  async (result) => {
 console.log(result.dataList)
 let webHook = await $.post("http://localhost:3000", {}, dimensionObj);
        console.log(webHook); });
});
```

Comment: Please refer this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34060487/chrome-extension-store-large-amounts-of-data